# This is a linq sanity check

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have the following three classes: Holder contains a list of Containers and Container contains a list of SubContainers. Am I using the proper linq to pull all empty SubContainers from the parent Holder?

```
class Holder
{
    List<Container> containers = new List<Containter>();

    public Holder()
    {
    }
}    

class Container
{
    List<SubContainer> subContainers = new List<SubContainer>();

    public Container()
    {
    }
}

class SubContainer
{
    bool Empty;

    public SubContainer()
    {
    }
}

var query =
    from a in Holder.containers
    from b in a.subContainers
    where b.Empty
    select b;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite. This is a job for `SelectMany`:

```
holder.containers.SelectMany(c => c.subContainers.Where(sc => sc.Empty))
```

**Update.** Well, I must admit a mistake. Your call and a `SelectMany` version s are identical. Here is what Jon Skeet [says about this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx):

> Secondary "from" clauses
>
> We've seen that the introductory "from" clause isn't actually
>   translated into a method call, but any subsequent ones are. The syntax
>   is still the same, but the translation uses SelectMany. In many cases
>   this is used just like a cross-join (Cartesian product) but it's more
>   flexible than that, as the "inner" sequence introduced by the
>   secondary "from" clause can depend on the current value from the
>   "outer" sequence.

Comment: Thanks, Andrei. Could you please explain how/why the results will differ with SelectMany?

Comment: if you just use select, then you are selecting a collection of collections. SelectMany will merge them into one.

Comment: Ok. Say I'm looking to use in an ObservableCollection. Just curious, would the use of my query work if I then call ObservableCollection<SubContainer> collection = new ObservableCollection<SubContainer>(query);

Comment: @philorube, actually I am wrong, and your version is identical to `SelectMany` - in fact, this *is* `SelectMany` call

Comment: @Andrei Wow! very interesting and good to know for future reference. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @philorube, for observable collection there should be no difference, just make sure to cast back to `ObservableCollection<SubContainer>` when needed